# HTML parser to word doc

Tags: html, html-parsing

I need to parse multiple HTML files and only pick up few tags from the file and save them in a word(.docx) file with certain formatting(certain words need to be bolded/indented etc.). Are there any pre built tools that I can use for the same? Or are there any external libraries that I can use to write the code for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use PHP, it's impossible to do this in clear HTML. Check for example: [HTML parse](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)